Maximum ratio of integrals subject to Lipschitz and integral constraints
Let $\mathcal{U}$ denote all $1$-Lipschitz, real-valued functions on $[-1, 1]$ (i.e., $|u(x) - u(y)| \leq |x - y|$)
I want to compute (or approximate) the following maximal ratio
$$
R(t, \gamma) = \sup_{u \in \mathcal{U} : \|u\|_2 \geq t} \Psi_\gamma(u), 
\quad \mbox{where} \quad 
\Psi_\gamma(u) = \frac{\int_{-1}^1 u^2(x) dx}{(\gamma + 1) \int_{-1}^1 u^2(x) |x|^\gamma  dx}
$$
where we denote $\|u\|_2^2 = \int_{-1}^1 u^2(x) dx$.
Intuitively, the worst thing to do should be to put most of the mass of $u$ near $0$ and decay from there. For instance, if we take $u_h(x) := h(1- |x/h|)_+$ for some $h \in (0, 1)$, then we obtain
$$
\Psi_\gamma(u_h) = \frac{c_\gamma}{h^\gamma} \quad \mbox{and} \quad 
\|u_h\|_2^2 = 2h^3/3. 
$$
where $c_\gamma = (\gamma + 3)(\gamma + 2)/3$.
Hence, taking $h^3 = 3t^2/2$, we get for $t^2 \leq 2/3$, that
$$
R(t, \gamma) \gtrsim t^{-2\gamma/3}.
$$
However, I am wondering if this inequality is also optimal in the sense that
$$
R(t, \gamma) \lesssim t^{-2\gamma/3},
$$
for $t$ sufficiently small and any $\gamma > 0$. The conjectured inequality above hides constants depending only on $\gamma$.

Should we read $x^\gamma$ as $|x|^\gamma$? If so, you are absolutely correct with your intuition and the formal proof is fairly straightforward.

Yes, thanks for the correction.

$\newcommand\ep\varepsilon\newcommand\de\delta$Let $p=\gamma>0$. It suffices to show that
$$\int_0^1 u^2\overset{\text{(?)}}\le(t\de)^{-2p/3}\int_0^1 x^p u(x)^2\,dx \tag{10}\label{10}$$
for some real $\de>0$ depending only on $p$, given that $u$ is $1$-Lipschitz.
Letting $H:=|f(0)|$, we have $|u(x)|\ge H-x$ for $x\in[0,1]$, so that, assuming that $H\le1$, for
$$s:=\|u\|_2 \tag{20}\label{20} $$
we have $s^2\ge\int_0^H(H-x)^2\,dx=H^3/3,$
so that $|u(0)|=H\le2s^{2/3}$ and hence
$$|u|\le2s^{2/3}+\ep\text{ on }[0,\ep],$$
where
$$\ep:=(Ct\de)^{2/3}\text{ and }C:=C_p:=2^{3/(2p)}, \tag{30}\label{30}$$
so that $\ep\in(0,1)$ if $\de$ and $t$ are small enough (which will be henceforth assumed). So,
$$\int_0^\ep u^2\le\ep(2s^{2/3}+\ep)^2\le2\ep(4s^{4/3}+\ep^2) \\
=8C^{2/3}\de^{2/3}t^{2/3}s^{4/3}+2C^2t^2\de^2\le s^2/2, \tag{40}\label{40}$$
because $0<t\le\|u\|_2=s$ and $\de>0$ is small enough.
Next, by Markov's inequality,
$$\int_0^1 x^p u(x)^2\,dx\ge\ep^p\int_\ep^1 u^2,$$
so that, in view of \eqref{30}, inequality \eqref{10} is implied by the inequality
$$(C^{2p/3}-1)\int_0^1 u^2\ge C^{2p/3}\int_0^\ep u^2,$$
which, in view of \eqref{20} and \eqref{30}, can be rewritten as $s^2\ge2\int_0^\ep u^2$, which in turn follows from \eqref{40}.
This completes the proof in the case when $H=|f(0)|\le1$.
The case $H=|f(0)|>1$ is much simpler. Indeed, then, since $H+x\ge|u(x)|\ge H-x$ for $x\in[0,1]$, the first integral in \eqref{10} is  $\le(H+1)^2\le4H^2$ whereas the second integral in \eqref{10} is
$$\ge\int_{1/3}^{2/3} x^p u(x)^2\,dx
\ge\frac13\,(1/3)^p(H-2/3)^2\ge\frac13\,(1/3)^p(1/3)^2 H^2.$$
This completes the proof of your conjecture. $\quad\Box$
